# What is the optimal way to stress test a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Given [recent events](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9870258#9870258), I have decided that Nukes everywhere are probably not the best way to stress test a server. Is there a way to do this in Feed the Beast Ultimate that doesn't result in massive damage to the landscape? If so, how?

Comment: I like your original idea better, even though I haven't heard any other ideas yet.

Comment: i have no idea what your showing me. thanks for the attempt

Comment: He stopped streaming, so [this is the chaos](http://www.twitch.tv/jigokuniku/b/416205472).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of just sucking up a lot of memory, the worst thing I've ever done is crowd a few chunks with obscene amounts of items.

If you create a bunch of [Igneous Extruders](http://ftbwiki.org/Igneous_Extruder) and set them to create cobblestone, and pipe it out of the machine to fall on the floor, they'll just pile the material up indefinitely until it lags your server to the point of being unusable.

Personal experience. (This is why you build redundancies into your automatic warehouses children.)

Comment: That seems painful. Is there an easier way to clean up though? And I want it to be realistic. Would someone on a server drop a billion cobblestone?

Comment: If you're using FTB and people set up quarries or farms or any of the automated systems, but don't add void-pipe redundancies on the storage output end, this will happen VERY OFTEN (not necessarily cobblestone but other materials).

It is very easy to clean up though. It'll lag intensely, but if one mod hops into the area in creative mode they'll suck up and delete the blocks. It'll be annoyingly slow to get to the stack of dropped items but everything will near-instantly clean up when you get within pickup distance.

Comment: You can also restart the server which clears dropped blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a very large amount of IC<sup>2</sup> solar panels. They are poorly optimized and perform a check of every single block above them (as there is no way to do raycast in minecraft that is known). A carpet of solar panels at bedrock will really put a strain on server CPU and memory.